# Can I get paid apps access in 10.04LTS?

Tags: 10.04, software-center, paid-applications

I don't see any option on my Software Center! I do not know if it is relevant, but I have created an Ubuntu One account (although I don't know how to inform the OS about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paid applications in the Software Centre were introduced in Ubuntu 10.10, so you cannot get them from 10.04.

Comment: Thank you. So, the only solution, apart from a clean install of 10.10 is to wait for the 11th LTS edition?

Comment: You can do an in-place install from 10.04 to 10.10. But if you'd prefer to stay with LTS releases then yes you need to wait until April 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Administration > Update Manager` then click the `Settings` button. In the dialog box that opens, switch to the `Updates` tab, check the box next to the 'backports' repository. When you click Close, Update Manager will prompt to reload your software repository list.

You only really want to install a newer version of Software Center, so if you find that one in the list of updates (read descriptions), then install it and see if it has support for paid applications. If not, then you can safely repeat the above procedure and uncheck the 'backports' repository without having to run the full upgrade. And yes, in this case you'd have to either to a clean install to 10.10 or wait for the next LTS version.

Comment: I don't think there is a version of Software Centre in the Maverick backports.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of that possibility. I did not see a backport of Software Center, so it seems I can not go this way.